# GCP Text-to-Speech API on Android Studio Emulator?

Tags: android-studio, google-cloud-platform, google-text-to-speech

My group and I can't seem to set the environment variable for Android Studio's Emulator as we keep getting the error in Android Studio that we need to set the environment variable of GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS. However, we are not sure how to do so in Android Studio.